# Concatenate multiple .csv dataframe with multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

I am concatenating multiple `dfs` which look like these:

```
                 X                  Y
                 mean   std size   mean         std  size
In_X                    
(10.424, 10.43] 10.425  NaN  1      0.003786    NaN   1
(10.43, 10.435] 10.4    NaN  0      NaN         NaN   0
```

When I didn't have multiindex `dfs`, I was using:

```
extension='csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
all_dfs = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ])
```

But this introduces a row:

```
mean   std size   mean          std  size
```

Every time a new `df` is concatenated to `all_dfs`.
How to have only the original multiindex header and avoid the introduction of the second-level header in the concatenated df?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read_csv` by defaults only take first row as header. You want to do specify two-row header with `header`:

```
all_dfs = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, header=[0,1] for f in all_filenames ])
```

Comment: change `header=[0,1`？

Comment: It worked, but for some reason,  instead of the original:

             `         X                  Y            `
              `   mean   std size   mean         std  size `

The main header got inverted to:

              `         Y                    X `
              `   mean   std size   mean         std  size ` 

the subheaders were also inverted so not a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your multi-index to regular columns like this:

```
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
```

And then use `pd.concat`